# Showing that the limit of an integral is bounded away from zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

I have a double integral of the following form.

\begin{equation}
G(t):=\iint p(x)q(y)\sum_{k}\lambda_{k}f_{k}(t(x-y))dxdy
\end{equation}
where the values $\lambda_{k}$ are all positive and $\sum_{k}\lambda_{k} = 1$. $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ both have compact support. $0\leq f_{k}(t(x-y))\leq 1$ and we know that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} f_{k}(t(x-y)) \neq 0$ and $f_{k}(0)=1$ for all $k$. I would like to prove that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} G(t) \neq 0
\end{equation}

I have tried taking the min of $\sum_{k}\lambda_{k}f_{k}(t(x-y))$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ but I then have to make extra assumptions on $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ for my hypothesis to hold. I am pretty sure that my hypothesis holds as is. I am wondering if I have to utilize a version of Fatou's lemma or Dominated convergence theorem.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you very much.